# What are the books Doctor Strange has finished before being given access to the Master's stacks?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, doctor-strange, doctor-strange-2016

In the movie Doctor Strange, as Strange is developing his magical understanding he returns a stack of books which Wong goes through before deciding to give Doctor Strange access to the library stacks reserved for Masters and those granted access.  Of the book titles he read off I was only able to catch and recall "The Key of Solomon".  What were the books he listed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Other than *The Keys of Solomon*, Dr Strange first reads...

- *The Book of the Invisible Sun*
- *Astronomia Nova*
- *Codex Emperium*

Comment: Plus all nine novels in the _A Song of Ice and Fire_ series, thanks to the Ancient One's occasional recreational use of the Time Stone.